# Can we configure logging system purely programmatically while conserving advantages of a separate configuration file?

Tags: java, logging, groovy, logback, log4j2

Every popular logging implementations use *.xml*, *.properties* files to configure precisely the way we want our logging system works.
As a java developer I also like the *java configuration style*, and prefer avoiding the verbose *.xml* files.

*Log4j2*, for example propose a way to set a [Programmatic Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/customconfig.html) instead of the classic *xml* version.

My questions are :

1. what are the advantages of conserving the *xml/properties* way of configuring logging ? It seems the programmatic style is not really popular and I wonder if it should be restricted to small projects or proof of concept only.
2. Subsidiary question : is there a manner to keep the configuration switching capability when using full *java configuration style* ?
3. Open question : I saw another configuration alternative with *logback* : defining logging [configuration through a groovy file](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html) found in the classpath... ok it is not pure Java but sound an interesting approach.
   **Bonus** : there is even an util to transform *xml* snippets to *groovy* equivalent (and it works apparently well)

Comment: Having a configuration file is better than hard coding your properties since it allows you to be more flexible when making changes because there will be no need to rebuild your classes.

Comment: Can we conserve this flexibility when using programmatic approach ? I didn't found anything on the subject..

Comment: Log4j 2 does not provide support for configuration via a full DSL. However, it does support scripts in certain portions of the configuration and supports reloading these scripts when they are modified.

Comment: thank for your comments.

Comment: Concerning Logback I noticed that an old (2013) attempt to implement full java configuration was tracked here : http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-764 . Also, a *potential workaround* is to keep the given default configuration then reset it programmatically + use the [JoranConfigurator](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#joranDirectly) to configure manually in java.